Index & Match in 3 Workbooks (1 to reference the other 2)
I am looking up a specific value that could exist in 1 of 2 workbooks.
Site A has its own Inventory
Site B has its own Inventory
Site C uses a sheet to verify items from both A and B by unique serial numbers. The serial number will only exist in one workbook, never both. Sites A and B list their inventory exactly the same in both workbooks to maintain continuity.
Right now I have a formula for a single workbook, which works fine. Our agency has added another warehouse and need to be able to reference both stock sheets.
This is the current formula I use for our search purposes...
=IFERROR((@INDEX([SiteA_INV.xlsx]Current!$A$2:$I$1910,SUMPRODUCT(([SiteA_INV.xlsx]Current!$A$2:$I$1910=$K$3)*(ROW([SiteA_INV.xlsx]Current!$A$2:$I$1910)))-@ROW([SiteA_INV.xlsx]Current!$A$1:$I$1),MATCH($J$6,[SiteA_INV.xlsx]Current!$A$1:$I$1,0))),"Enter Search Criteria")

Just need to know what to add to this that might work... or something else altogether if needed.

Duplicate that formula for Site B, then wrap the two formulas in another IFERROR.

I have limited knowledge.... wrapping them together is my downfall at this point

Solved with some tinkering... figured out the wrap and got it up and running... thanks for the push in the right direction
